# Measurable selection involving measure valued random variable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of finite signed measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ endowed with the narrow topology (i.e. the initial topology w.r.t. $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the set of real valued, continuous and bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$) and the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mu: \Omega \to \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be measurable and let us define the multifunction
$$F : \Omega \rightrightarrows C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d):=\{ \varphi \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^d) \mid |\varphi|_{\infty} \le 1 \}$$
(where $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the Banach space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity with the supremum norm) as
$$F(\omega) := \left \{ \varphi \in C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d) \mid \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi \text{ d} \mu_{\omega} \ge \frac{|\mu_{\omega}|}{2} \right \}, $$
where $|\mu_{\omega}|$ is the total variation norm of $\mu_{\omega}$.

Can we find a measurable selection $f: \Omega \to C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of $F$, meaning that $f$ is measurable and $f(\omega) \in F(\omega)$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$?

I tried with the [Kuratowski–Ryll-Nardzewski measurable selection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_and_Ryll-Nardzewski_measurable_selection_theorem) but I am not able to prove that $\{ \omega \in \Omega \mid F(\omega) \cap U \}$ is measurable for every $U \subset C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ open.

Any hint would be really appreciated!

Comment: If $|\mu_{\omega}|(\mathbb{R}^d)<a$ wouldn't you be in trouble?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I would get $F(\omega)= \emptyset$, hence no selection. Let me edit the question a little bit.

Comment: Edited. The point is that I would like to have a measurable way to select, for every $\omega \in \Omega$ a $\varphi \in C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ s.t. the integral $\int \varphi d \mu$ is really close to the total variation of $\mu(\omega)$.

Comment: I think it is better to avoid $\mu(\omega)$ and use instead $\mu_{\omega}$ especially in $\int \varphi d\mu(\omega)$.

Comment: I don't think the function $\omega\mapsto |\mu_\omega|$ will usually be measurable.

Comment: It seems to me that $\omega \mapsto <\mu_{\omega}, \varphi>$ is measurable for every $\varphi \in C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ so that $\omega \mapsto |\mu_{\omega}|$ is measurable being the supremum of a family of measurable functions.

Comment: But $C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is not separable.

Comment: Why not? $\mathbb{R}^d$ is locally compact and second countable, hence $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ should be separable and then also $C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is separable.

Comment: @Bremen000 You are right, I did not see that these are functions vanishing at infinity. Sorry.

Comment: One way to establish the required measurability needed for the  Kuratowski–Ryll-Nardzewski measurable selection theorem is by showing that for each $\phi\in C_{0,1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the function $\omega\mapsto d\big(\phi,F(\omega)\big)$ is measurable. That might work here.

Comment: I would forget about the KRN Thm and do instead the toy model: let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions $\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with pointwise finite sups, find a measurable map $\phi:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{\phi(\omega)}(\omega)\ge \sup_n f_n(\omega) -1$ for all $\omega$. Then adapt to the present question by leveraging the separability of $C_{0,1}$.

Comment: I think this is straightforward by what I call the "lexicographic" method: fix a countable dense sequence $(f_n)$ in $C_{0,1}$. Then as you point out, $\omega\mapsto|\mu_\omega|=\sup\int f_n\,d\mu_\omega$. Let $N(\omega)=\min\{n\colon \int f_n\,d\mu_\omega\ge \frac 12|\mu_\omega|\}$. This is measurable because $N^{-1}\{1,\ldots,k\}=\bigcup_{j=1}^k \{\omega\colon \int f_j\,d\mu_\omega\ge \frac 12|\mu_\omega|\}$.

Comment: Did that answer your question? If so, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, it does, please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is straightforward by what I call the "lexicographic" method: fix a countable dense sequence $(f_n)$ in $_{0,1}$. Then as you point out, $\omega\mapsto|\mu_\omega|=\sup\int f_n\,d\mu_\omega$. Let $N(\omega)=\min\{n:\int f_n\,d\mu_\omega\ge\frac12|\mu_\omega|\}$. This is measurable because $N^{-1}\{1,\ldots,k\}=\bigcup_{j=1}^k \{\omega\colon\int f_j\,d\mu_\omega\ge \frac12|\mu_\omega|\}$.